# re-usable code for Django's migrations, which works also outside migrations

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

This is about creating users, groups and more instances in Django, in bulk manner,
and re-using the same creation code in the regular app and in migrations as well.

There is a problem in `RunPython` when code tries to use some models imported in a regular way.

---

For example below is true when running migration
(`apps` is `django.db.migrations.state.StateApps` argument)

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

assert apps.ready
assert User != apps.get_model('auth', 'User')

>>> User
<class 'django.contrib.auth.models.User'>                                                                                                                                                                                                     
>>> app.get_model('auth', 'User')                                                                                                                                                                                                             
<class '__fake__.User'>                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
>>> type(app.get_model('auth', 'User'))                                                                                                                                                                                                       
<class 'django.db.models.base.ModelBase'>
```

Then using both kinds of models together will result in `TypeError`
like:

`TypeError: 'Group' instance expected, got <Group: Bots>`

Of course, a question is how to avoid changes in code, but have code working with both models (migrations and regular app)

am I forced to load Django's commands inside migrations?

Comment: If you're loading data at migration time, why would you then want to be able to load the same data from an app?

Comment: who said/wrote "same"? code is same, not data.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstanding. Loading data during migrations is different because things aren't in the same state. I don't think you can have the same code during migrations as you might with an app running.